Foreign key constraint vs Application Level Constraint
sorry for my bad english

@Entity()
export class Account {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  accountNumber: number;

  @Column({ type: 'double precision' })
  balance: number;

  @OneToOne(() => Currency)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'currency_signature' })
  currency: Currency;

  @OneToOne(() => User, { nullable: false })
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;
}




i have this entity/table in my postgres database(im using typeorm),
      if (!user) throw new BadRequestException('There is no user with that id');
      const account = await this.accountRepository.create({
        ...createAccountDto,
        user,
        currency: { currency_signature: 'USC' },
      });

and i have this create query
my question is, do i need to check for the existence of the currency table data first? or just let the account table handle it using foreign key constraint, because the account table know if the data im inserting is in the currency table or not from the foreign key constraint?
from my perspective i think i dont need to make a find query to check the existence of the currency signature first, because the account table already check it for me using foreign_key constraint, if i make a find query to check the existence of the currency, its just going to be another query and just adding extra job to the database?
what do you guys think?

Why do you even store currency in a different table? There are just a few currencies world wide, you won't use all currencies, most likely just a few, and storing USD or EUR takes just 3 bytes in a CHAR(3). Sometimes you have to be practical.

It is fine to depend on database data integrity constraints without additional application level checks. It is not acceptable to depend on application level checks to enforce data integrity. The query before write approach is useful when it is desirable to users of multiple potential issues whereas depending on database constraints will only report the first encountered exception.

@FrankHeikens, perhaps the currency table has additional attributes and isn't only used constrain account.currency_signature.

Shouldn't the @OneToOne relation from account to currency be @ManyToOne? I'm assuming that a currency can be used by more than one account.

A foreign key constraint is so different from an application constraint, there is no "which one is better". Do you want data integrity or not? If you do, use a foreign key. If not, don't use a foreign key.

@JohnH yes, you are right, the constraint should be @ManyToOne, i already fix that code. so based on your answer, its okay to just depend on foreign key constraint right, without the need for checking it at the application level check?

Yes, it's completely appropriate to depend on foreign key constraints to enforce data integrity.

Comments aren't meant for extended dialogue. There is an area, Discussions (currently in beta), that is more appropriate, especially for topics that are likely to elicit opinions instead of technically provable answers.

You don't need to check the existence of the currency before inserting the account; the foreign key constraint in the Account table will enforce that for you. Adding a separate check would just create unnecessary database queries. Just handle any potential errors that arise from the foreign key constraint during the insert operation.
try {
  const account = await this.accountRepository.save({
    ...createAccountDto,
    user,
    currency: { currency_signature: 'USC' },
  });
} catch (error) {
  if (error.code === '23503') { // Postgres foreign key violation error code
    throw new BadRequestException('Invalid currency');
  }
  throw error;
}

